# Custom Caption for Image Inside Multilevel Numbering

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

Well, before I dive into overriding the entire caption's numbering, I want to ask here.

I used `multilevel numbering` to define my chapter number and subchapter number. However, I'm surprised that when I added a caption, the chapter number will be always in roman numerals like example below, although I set the numbering Format

[image].

```
Chapter I
1. Part A
   <SomeImage>
   Figure I.1 <SomeDescription>
2. Part B
Chapter II
1. Part A
2. Part B
```

What I expected is something like:

```
Chapter I
1. Part A
   <SomeImage>
   Figure 1.1 <SomeDescription>
2. Part B
Chapter II
1. Part A
2. Part B
```

Is this intended behaviour? If so, what is the best course of action to achieve the expected result?

I'm using Microsoft Office 2013 Pro Plus anyway. Perhaps I'm missing something, or should I run into LaTex..

Comment: It is normal only if you are using Roman numerals for chapter's Heading 1. I don't believe you can use Roman numerals there and expect Arabic numerals somewhere else. Probably Microsoft sees this as consistency :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are missing anything obvious. Whether you should head for LaTex or anything else is a decision only you are in a position to make.

I may have overlooked something, but the problem(s) with trying to get Word to behave better in this area really down to the fact that Word has a very specific model as to how this stuff works, and an implementation that does not give you very much flexibility.

For example, at one time, it was only possible to define multi-level numbering schemes (then called "Outline numbering") based on the "Heading n" paragraph styles. Although that constraint no longer exists, the part of the numbering scheme to do with caption numbering still assumes that your chapters start with "Heading n" styles.

By default, what Word does when you specify that you want the chapter number is to insert a { STYLEREF } field to insert the sequence number from the heading level you specified.

If that sequence number happened to be a number, say "4" and you actually wanted the Roman Numeral "IV", you could at least add a formatting switch (e.g. *Roman) to present the 4 as IV. However, if the Chapter numbering is Roman, you just don't get that option - the equivalent *Arabic switch only works if Word thinks the actual number in the Chapter level heading is numeric (and it doesn't think "IV" is numeric.

One way you could conceivably work around that would be to use VBA to set up a number of document variables named "I", "II", "III", "IV" etc., with values "1","2","3","4" etc.

Then instead of the { STYLEREF 1 \s } field code that Word inserts, you could use

{ DOCVARIABLE { STYLEREF 1 \s } } to "map" IV to 4.

And in fact, it nearly works, and even when you enter a table of Figures, that displays what you expect.

BUT, the trouble is that when you next insert a Figure caption, Word tries to "fix up" your existing captions by inserting the { STYLEREF } field that it can no longer see in there. So you end up with "4-IV-1" etc.

There are other ways you can set up your own numbering schemes, but you will generally lose some other feature of Word (typically, the ability to use the UI to insert a cross-reference) by doing so. My view is that with cross-referencing, it just isn't worth trying to get Word to work in a way is constantly at cross-purposes with its "design".

Comment: i see, i tried fiddling with the field code with no luck. so basically i'm going to override everything once i'm done adding captions - i have no luxury to move to LaTex yet.. time constraint. Thank you for your clarification, and `{ DOCVARIABLE { STYLEREF 1 \s } }` is a considerable idea.

Comment: FWIW it doesn't have to be a DOCVARIABLE - using docvariables is just a good way to make it difficult to modify things accidentally. But you could use { SET I 1 }{ SET II 2 } etc. at the beginning of the document or in a header and { REF { STYLEREF 1 \s } } (check required!) or for a relatively small number of chapters, set up custom document properties and use { DOCPROPERTY { STYLEREF 1 \s } }